# How to get specific adjacent characters of a string and add it to an another string in C

Tags: c, printf, c-strings

I have an abstract concept to use a for-loop to get specific adjacent characters of a string and add it to a stack, basically take all the constants of a string expression and add it to the stack separately; For example string: "1111+(2222-3333)" would be put in to the stack like "1111","2222", and "3333". I have a code below to start with that abstract concept but first trying it out with a simple one, and unfortunately it doesn't output the desired result of copying the specific adjacent characters.

```
char expression[20]={""},sub[20]={""};
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c",&expression);
    sub[15]=expression[15];
    sub[16]=expression[16];
    sub[17]=expression[17];
    sub[18]=expression[18];
    printf("%c %c %c %c\n",sub[15],sub[16],sub[17],sub[18]); //to check if copied successfully
    printf("sub= %s",sub); //doesnt print expected output
```

Comment: What does it output?

Comment: @Das Falsche Gewinn The array sub is initialized by zeroes. So the first character of the array is zero. Nothing will be outputted by the call printf("sub= %s",sub); because the function will decide that the array contains an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

After this declaration

```
char expression[20]={""},sub[20]={""};
```

all elements of the array `sub` contain zeroes.

You changed elements of the array starting from the position 15

```
sub[15]=expression[15];
sub[16]=expression[16];
sub[17]=expression[17];
sub[18]=expression[18];
```

The elements before the position still store zeroes.

So this call of `printf`

```
printf("sub= %s",sub);
```

assumes that the array contains an empty string because it first character is the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

Instead you could write

```
printf("sub= %s",sub + 15 );
```

Or you could change the assignments like

```
sub[0]=expression[15];
sub[1]=expression[16];
sub[2]=expression[17];
sub[3]=expression[18];
```

and then use

```
printf("sub= %s",sub);
```

Pay attention to that the second argument of this call of `scanf`

```
scanf("%[^\n]%*c",&expression);
```

is incorrect. You have to write

```
scanf("%[^\n]%*c",expression);
```